Moving from Blender 2.79b to 4.2: stop viewport objects from appearing bulbous when they are not
I've used Blender 2.79b for a long time and am trying to move myself to Blender 4.2.  One thing I can't sort out is the viewport: in Blender 4.2 viewport objects are shaded so that they appear bulbous when they are not.  For instance, this helical gear is flat on top and has nice square (well, slanted but you know what I mean) teeth, but in my recent installation of Blender 4.2 you'd be forgiven for thinking it was all bulbous and horrible:

Here is the same object in Blender 2.79b:

This is what I need (for 3D printing purposes), I can see what's what.  I've tried the "flat" view in Blender 4.2 but that just gives me a white-out:

How do I persuade Blender 4.2 to give me the more realistic viewport views of Blender 2.79b?  It is possible that I configured something to achieve this in Blender 2.79b many moons ago and need to do something similar in Blender 4.2 but I've no idea what...

Try right-click > Shade Flat?

Aha, yes: is there a way to make that the default for new objects?

It is the default for new objects! You must have somehow shaded it smooth.

This was imported from an STL file, not otherwise modified.  I guess importing is somehow treated differently to "new".

Yes indeed. My comment assumed that it was created in Blender. It probably has Custom Split Normals on it. Click on the green triangle (Data) tab on the Properties panel and open the Geometry Data section. You'll probably see a button saying 'Clear Custom Split Normals' and clicking that should sort the problem without having to Shade Flat. They were probably added by whatever created the STL file.

The way Blender handles flat/smooth shading changed since 2.79. Was this stl file imported into blender 2.79 and then that .blend file open in 4.2, or was the stl file imported into 4.2 directly? In the first case, that could be a mere compatibility issue, i doubt there is much we can do. In the second case, i'd have a look at the stl import options.

Doesn't seem to have a Clear Custom Split Normals button under there, just + Add Custom Split Normals.  The STL file was imported directly into Blender in both cases.  I guess it's fine for a one-off thing to do the right-click and Shade Flat, now that I know.
